# UWP: Assets being visible during debug but not in store release

Tags: xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, windows-store

In my app, there is an about section with the app icon in it:

```
<Border Background="Gray" Margin="0,0,12,0" Width="136" Height="136">
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.scale-400.png" Width="68"/>
</Border>
```

During debug it behaves as expected:
[debug with asset visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd8kP.png)

But after uploading it to the store and having it downloaded with another client, it looks like this:
[result after store upload - asset not visible, just background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzk38.png)

The build settings for that specific files inside Visual Studio should be correct, but you can check:
[asset properties: Build Action = Content; Copy to Output Directory = Copy always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpWAR.png)

How can I manage to display the asset in store release too?

Comment: Try running the app in release mode and testing it

Comment: It's the same as debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png" Width="68"/>
```

just use normal StoreLogo name, without the scale extension, the scale extension is for store to figure out best image on store for different screens sizes.

Comment: happy to help :)